# Jquery Animation for (or instead of) .show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to jazz up my .show() jquery function so that the previously hidden text appears in an interesting way. Any suggestions?

I am really interested in any animation that you like. Additionally, this text is at the bottom of the page and I want to make sure the users window moves down so that the new text is in the middle of their browser.

Comment: I am really interested in any animation that you like. Additionally, this text is at the bottom of the page and I want to make sure the users window moves down so that the new text is in the middle of their browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.fadeIn()`,`.slideDown();`.